# NSRegularExpression to remove digits within parentheses at the end of a line

Tags: regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I feel like I've exhausted every regex I can think of and read every piece of NSRegularExpression documentation I can get my hands on, but I still can't figure this out.

I have some NSStrings that end with a digit within parentheses (something like "blah blah blah (33)". I want to remove the parentheses, whitespace, and digits, but only if it matches at the end of the line and only if the contents of the parentheses are digits only (the previous example would be "blah blah blah"). My regex below is close, but it will match if there are non-digit characters in the regex and it will match if there is more content at the end of the string, after the parentheses:

```
  NSArray *testStrings = @[@"hello (2)", @"hello (22)", @"hello (22) a", @"hello (2s)"];

  for (NSString *msg in testStrings) {

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"[\\s\(\\d+\\)$]"
                                                                           options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error: &error];

    if (!error) {

      NSLog(@"%lu", [regex numberOfMatchesInString:msg options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])]);

      NSString* plainText = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: msg
                                                            options: 0
                                                              range: NSMakeRange(0, [msg length])
                                                       withTemplate: @""];

      NSLog(@"%@", plainText);
    }
  }
```

Below is the output:

```
test[93719:10248184] 4
test[93719:10248184] hello
test[93719:10248184] 5
test[93719:10248184] hello
test[93719:10248184] 6
test[93719:10248184] helloa
test[93719:10248184] 4
test[93719:10248184] hellos
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: stribizhevs answer is spot on, although do you want to match a string like `hello (1) world (23)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
\s*\(\d+\)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB4mZ9/1)

In Objective-C, decalre as `@"\\s*\\(\\d+\\)$"`.

Your regex - `[\s\(\d+\)$]` - encloses all the subpatterns into square brackets thus creating a character class that matches 1 character: whitespace, or `(`, or digit, or `+`, or `)`, or `$`.

So, you need to remove the square brackets, and add a `*` quantifier to the whitespace shorthand class `\s` to that all leading whitespace could be matched.

Comment: If you have any more doubts, please feel free to drop a comment.